# What's wrong with this simple code - Substring?

Tags: javascript

What's wrong in here?

```
function setMaxLenght(textbox, length) {
    var currentLength = textbox.value.length;
    var minimum = Math.min(currentLength, length);

    textbox.value = textbox.value.subString(0, minimum - 1);
}
```

When the code reaches the last line, it throws this error:

```
Uncaught type error: Object 1 has no method 'subString'
```

Comment: JavaScript is case-sensitive. `subString` should be `substring`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because there is no subString method.

It is all lowercase

```
textbox.value.substring(0
                 ^
```

[MDN substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring)